# writing character array to a table

Tags: r, transpose, sapply

I want to transpose the output given by the last command and write it to a data.frame. I want that dataframe to have 2 columns. First column will have column names and the second column will have data type for the column in each row. How could I achieve it? I tried variety of things but didnt get what I am looking for

```
smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
smoke <- as.data.frame(smoke)
table1=sapply (smoke, class)
table1
```

Comment: You should include what you tried (show research effort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also skip the `table1` part and go straight from `smoke` to the desired result.

```
> data.frame(nm = names(smoke), cl = sapply(unname(smoke), class))
#   nm      cl
# 1 V1 numeric
# 2 V2 numeric
# 3 V3 numeric
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer really. No need for intermediary datasets here at all.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
data.frame(var.name = names(table1), var.class = table1, row.names=NULL)
#  var.name var.class
#1       V1   numeric
#2       V2   numeric
#3       V3   numeric
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the `melt` command.

```
library(reshape2)

smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
smoke <- as.data.frame(smoke)
table1 <- sapply (smoke, class)
smoke.melt <- melt(smoke)

levels(smoke.melt$variable) <- table1

> smoke.melt
  variable value
1  numeric    51
2  numeric    92
3  numeric    68
4  numeric    43
5  numeric    28
6  numeric    22
7  numeric    22
8  numeric    21
9  numeric     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert table1 to data.frame and adjust:

```
dd = data.frame(table1)
dd
    table1
V1 numeric
V2 numeric
V3 numeric

dd$VarName = rownames(dd)
dd
    table1 VarName
V1 numeric      V1
V2 numeric      V2
V3 numeric      V3

dd = dd[,c(2,1)]
dd
   VarName  table1
V1      V1 numeric
V2      V2 numeric
V3      V3 numeric

names(dd)[2] = "type"
dd
   VarName    type
V1      V1 numeric
V2      V2 numeric
V3      V3 numeric
```